# dropdown bootstrap menu is not getting populated on webpage

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a header file where I am trying to include a bootstrap dropdown which will have the user id and two more options in the dropdown. In the header file I have created a new div for dropdown and and linked it a php file where I have the logic for populating the user id information for dropdown.

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <!--<style>{height:150px; width:1300px;}</style>-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="Public">
    <title><?php echo $page_title?></title>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"</script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script_dbafactory.js?<?php echo rand(0,511);?>"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link href="css/style_header.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  </head>      
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-4 column">
          <img alt="logo" src="./images/source.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 column dbf">
          <h2>DBA Factory</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
          <div class="tabbable" id="tabs-775712">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li>
                <a href="../dbafactory/home_page.php?sub=1" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="../dbafactory/form_page.php?sub=2" data-toggle="tab">Submit a project</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="../dbafactory/view_table.php?sub=3" data-toggle="tab">All Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#panel-4" data-toggle="tab">Innovative Ideas</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#panel-5" data-toggle="tab">Matchmaker</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#panel-6" data-toggle="tab">Meet the Team</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <?php include "userlogin.php"; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
  $('#userlogin').dropdown('toggle');
</script>
```

userlogin.php

```
if ($loginid!="")
{
  echo "<a id=\"userlogin\" role=\"button\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" href=\"#\">" .$loginid. "<span class=\"caret\"></span></a>";
  //echo "<li role=\"presentation\"><a role=\"menuitem\" tabindex=\"-1\" href=\"#\">" .$loginid. "</a></li>";
  echo "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\" aria-labelledby=\"userlogin\">";
  echo "<li role=\"presentation\"><a role=\"menuitem\" tabindex=\"-1\" href=\"#\">Settings</a></li>";
  echo "<li role=\"presentation\" class=\"divider\"></li>";
  echo "<li role=\"presentation\"><a role=\"menuitem\" tabindex=\"-1\" href=\"http://profilelink\">My Profile</a></li>";
  echo "<li role=\"presentation\"><a role=\"menuitem\" tabindex=\"-1\" href=\"https://logoutpage\"> Sign Out </a></li>";
  echo "</ul>";
}
else
{
  echo "<a id=\"userlogin\" role=\"button\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" href=\"#\"> User <span class=\"caret\"></span></a>";
  echo "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\" aria-labelledby=\"userlogin\">";
  echo "<li role=\"presentation\"><a role=\"menuitem\" tabindex=\"-1\" href=\"https://reloginpage\"> Sign In </a></li>";
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

I am able to get the userid on the main login page. The dropdown works fine for me on jsfiddle but not on the concerned page. When I debug with Firebug.  I see the  tag not highlighted but the  tag i.e. userid highlighted. Can this be a problem?

Can someone please let me know what is the problem here? How do i proceed solving this and debugging?

Comment: "How do i proceed solving this" -> add the JSFIDDLE! :)

Comment: is the header.php included in the actual <head></head> tags of your document?

Comment: The code you see here has been replicated from JSFIDDLE!

Comment: Eah, ok, JS fiddle would not work, A fiddle would be nice. ;) Looks chaotic, you need to have `<!DOCTYPE html>, <html>, <head> and <body>` to make it cross-browser work.

Comment: @SidneyWidmer - the header.php file has all the required js and css files in the <head></head> tags. But below that I have a logic to include bootsrap tabs and dropdowns. For one of the dropdowns, I am pulling all the information I need from a different "userlogin.php". Makes sense?

Comment: @dollarvar - made the edits...

Comment: Ok, you have problems in your PHP. If you want to use quotes in your echo, you have to switch them `echo "<div class='...'...>"`.

Comment: @dollarvar - can you be a little bit more detailed ? in the header.php file? Can you post an answer?

Comment: No I cannot, I tend to only post answers if I can be sure they work. ;) Since a fiddle. Forget my last comment, you escaped the `\"`, should also work. ;) But I keep looking.

Comment: "I see the tag not highlighted but the tag i.e. userid highlighted." What do you mean, can you update that in your question and notify me? And can you try to `echo` *anything* on your page?

Comment: I mean `echo` anything from userlogin.php on header.php. Is the adress wrong, like in missing directory or something?

Comment: @dollarvar - have you used firebug for firefox? in that i cannot see the <ul> tags as highlighted. The ones which have been rendered successfully are highlighted. I am able to login the user id on the header page.

Comment: wait, so you have `<ul>` tags on your header.php, but they are not populated, is that it? Can you post a screenshot of the firebug debugger? (Perhaps moving to chat?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46882/discussion-between-rond-and-dollarvar)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include `<?php include "userlogin.php"; ?>` in the `<body>` of your document. You can't output divs and lists in your `<head>`.

It's also good practice to include all the JS libraries e.t.c right at the END of your body (directly before the `</body>` tag). Like that the rendering of the site doesn't get blocked.

Edit:
@rond Just in case you haven't figured it out yet, I created a gist (not tested) how this should look -> https://gist.github.com/sidneywidmer/8839857

Comment: I just put the entire header file there. I think it is as per what you said in your answer. Please let me know if i am wrong. @sidneywidmer

Comment: Ok, wait, only the libraries and not the jQuery-user-script? **That would not work.** And how does the "rendering of the HTML" get blocked? Do you have any reference for that? Thanks

Comment: The jquery user script is at the end of the header file. I am not sure how does it get blocked...as i said the <ul> tag does not populate.

Comment: @dollarvar here is a nice explanation http://www.lognormal.com/blog/2012/12/12/the-script-loader-pattern/

Comment: @SidneyWidmer Ok, thanks, understood, never looked into that, actually I just meant "technically you cannot have the libraries after the code" and overlooked your "e.t.c.". ;)